# Ajax - All request are Done/Completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a difficulty to know when all Ajax requests are completed because I need this information to call another function.
Difficulty are to know when my 4/5 function with requests are completed. I use native function of ajax and none is working for me.
I used Chrome, and async requests.

Someone Helps me

I use this(not work):

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  alert("Completed");
});
```

and this (not Work):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {   alert("Completed"); });
```

Both ways I try use in another function thal calls all requests:
Example:

```
function Init() 
{  Search("123");  Search2("1234");  Search3("12345");
... }
```

Extract one (of 5 requests,others are very similar ) of my request:

```
function Search(user) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'www.example.com/' + user,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            try {
                if (response != null) {
                    alert("Have Data");
                } else {
                    alert("are empty");
                }
            } catch (err) {
                alert("error");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
}); }
```

Comment: am working on a similar problem, per documentation cross-domain requests don't exec the error function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom trigger

```
$(document).trigger('ajaxDone')
```

and call it when ever you finished your ajax requests.

Then you can listen for it

```
$(document).on('ajaxDone', function () {
//Do something
})
```

If you want to keep track of multiple ajax calls you can set a function that counts how many "done" values were passed to it, and once all are finished, you can fire the event.

Place the call for this function in each of the 'success' and 'error' events of the ajax calls.

Update:
You can create a function like so

```
var completedRequests= 0
function countAjax() {
    completedRequests+=1
    if(completedRequests==whatEverNumberOfRequestsYouNeed) {
          $(document).trigger('ajaxDone');
    }     
}
```

Call this function on every success and error events. 
Then, ajaxDone event will be triggered only after a certain number of requests.

If you wanna track specific ajax requests you can add a variable to countAjax that checks which ajax completed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. You suggest I put the trigger "$(document).trigger('ajaxDone')"  on event "success" or "error" and count how many requests are done Right?

How can i can count this? in "//Do something" do "if" count equals number requests are done?
Sorry but I'm new on this programming language.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

have you tried putting it in a done function? something like...

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: 'www.example.com/' + user,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'JSONP'
    }).done(function (data) {
        code to execute when request is finished;
    }).fail(function () {
       code to do in event of failure
    });
```

bouncing off what Michael Seltenreich said, his solution, if i understand where you guys are going with this...might look something like:

```
    var count = 0;

function checkCount(){
 if(count == 5 ){
    //do this, or fire some other function 
 }
}
#request one
 $.ajax({
        url: 'www.example.com/' + user,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'JSONP',
    }).done( function(data){
        count += 1
        checkCount()
        })

 #request two
 $.ajax({
        url: 'www.example.com/' + user,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'JSONP',
    }).done( function(data){
        count += 1
        checkCount()
        })
```

and do it with your five requests. If that works out for you please make sure to mark his question as the answer;)

Comment: Hi, I see this solution on internet but the problem are when I have many requests asyncronous.
Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer to show you one approach based on Michael Seltenreich's solution since you were not sure how to implement his idea. He may have a better implementation, if he comes back to this thread. Either way, if this works out, make sure you mark HIS answer as correct since it is his solution.